# jQuery Address - Deep linking - Support for LIVE, content insert after Page Load

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

i'm building a web app which has a navigation that loads after doc ready which contains a bunch of links...

I want these links to be deep linked and am trying to use jQuery Address however it doesn't seem to work with content that isn't hard coded on the page...

Has anyone got jQuery address or another jQuery deep linking solution working?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try Sammy.js instead, here is a [Sammy deep linking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6795019/deep-linking-with-sammy-js) question on SO.  live() is deprecated in favor of delegate() and on() so that might be an issue.