# Deep-linking with Sammy.js?

Tags: javascript, sammy.js

I recently built a website using the sammy.js framework. The site includes a portfolio page with a grid of thumbnails that link to the detail page for each portfolio piece. All of this works.

What I cannot seem to figure out how to do is be able to provide someone a link to a specific project on the site (ex: www.thesite.com/#/work-detail/some-project) and have it run the work-detail route with "some-project" as the variable that gets passed for it to load the correct content.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, this doesn't work?

```
get('#/work-detail/:project', function() {
        alert(this.params['project']);
});
```